# How to add a download video button to HTML5 player?

Tags: javascript, html, button, video, download

I'm working on this site: http://animevid-episode.webflow.io/

I'd like to give users the possibility to download the video I put in the player. Do you know how to add a "download video" button to this player or any other generic HTML5 video player?

Actually, I can only find on Google about tools to download video and how to prevent downloading. I guess it's possible with JavaScript, but really can't find how. Any suggestions or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<video id="V1" >
     <source src="filename.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
     HTML5 Video .
     <a href="filename.mp4" download>Download video</a> . 
</video>
```

Comment: Moreover, if you would like to name the file-to-be-downloaded something other than the actual file name, you can specify a value for the download attribute, for example, `download="specialName.mp4"` inside of the `a`nchor tag. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
<video id="Video1" >
     <source src="something.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
     HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
     <a href="something.ogv">Download the video</a> file. 
</video>
```

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but it's ok, really thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<video control>
     <source src="https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1560754230~acl=%2A%2F1361268216.mp4%2A~hmac=d30db59f387628f38a3f9e7a74f2d359a29093b7c6cedf8a69ec2cdbe3e6cc88/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3225/13/341126404/1361268216.mp4" type="video/mp4" /> 
     HTML5 Video .
     <a href="https://gcs-vimeo.akamaized.net/exp=1560754230~acl=%2A%2F1361268216.mp4%2A~hmac=d30db59f387628f38a3f9e7a74f2d359a29093b7c6cedf8a69ec2cdbe3e6cc88/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/3225/13/341126404/1361268216.mp4" download>Download video</a> . 
</video>
```

Comment: vimeo URL timestamp over so not run code in this condition

Comment: it's controls not control